# creating a program and getting these errors

Tags: c, pic

Can any one help with the errors im receiving

> c55 error:general error
>
> c55 error:faliure

I'm trying to compile the code and these are the errors im receiving and I dont know how to correct them at all

> failed to locate output file 'pic control 1.obj'

```
#include <system.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char state, nxtstate, inbyte,g1,g2;

void checkS1S2()
{
    inbyte=porta;

    if ((inByte & 0x0F) == 0x07) //70%
    {
        nextstate =1; // turn on G1
    }

    if ((inByte & 0xF0) == 0x20) // 50%
    {
        nextstate =2; // turn on G2
    }

    if ((inByte & 0xF0) == 0xFF) // 100%
    {
        nextstate =3; // turn on G1 and G2
    }

    if (((inByte & 0xF0) == 0x00) || ((inByte & 0xF0) == 0x01))
    {
        nextState = 4; // TurnoFF G2
    }

    if (((inByte & 0x0F) == 0x00) || ((inByte & 0x0F) == 0x01)  || ((inByte & 0x0F) == 0x02) )
    {
        nextState = 5; // TurnoFF G1
    }
}

void state1(void)
{
    bitset(portb1); // switch on G1
    nextstate = 1;
    g1 =1;
}//end of state1.

void state2(void)
{
    bitset(portb2); // switch on G2
    nextstate = 1;
    g2 =1;
}//end of state2

void state3(void)
{
    checktime;
    {
        if time up && (g1 ==1) && (g2 ==1);
            state6;
        else
            state1;
    }
}

void state6(void)
{
    // switch OFF G0,G1,G2
    bitclear(portb,0);
    bitclear(portb,1);
    bitclear(portb,2);
    bitset(portb3);
    nextstate = 1;
    g1 =0;
    g2=0;
}//end of state6

void state4(void)
{
    bitclear(portb,1); // Switch OFF G1
    nextstate =1;
    g1 =0;
}

void state5()
{
    bitclear(portb,2); // Switch OFF G2
    g2 =0;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Configure RA0-RA3 as S1 , RA4-RA7 as S2
    // Configure RB0 as G0 , RB1 as G1 , RB2 as G2 and RB3 as LED
    config();
    nxtstate=0;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure there is more of error text... And.. have you heard of punctuation? It's impossible to differ between your and cited text.

Comment: in `state3` function you have `checktime;`.....I guess it's an error. Moreover the following if is totally wrong...`if time up && (g1 ==1) && (g2 ==1);`

Comment: is the missing file called "pic control 1.obj"? and have you put quotes around it in the command or escaped out the spaces?

Comment: Don't retype errors.  Cut and paste the actual errors and quote them in your post.  You are missing the line numbers where the errors occurred.

Comment: Fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

Your function `state3` contains line that are not valid C code:

```
void state3(void)
{
    checktime;
    {
        if time up && (g1 ==1) && (g2 ==1);
            state6;
        else
            state1;
    }
}
```

I assume that your intention was to add a comment and to invoke functions. In thart case you should do this:

```
void state3(void)
{
    /* checktime */
    {
        if time up && (g1 ==1) && (g2 ==1);
            state6();
        else
            state1();
    }
}
```

Probably the checktime should be an boolean expression:

```
void state3(void)
{
    if (checktime)
    {
        if time up && (g1 ==1) && (g2 ==1);
            state6();
        else
            state1();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the question left enough room for guessing.